# How do I write this $t^2$ as a linear combination of polynomials in the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this homework problem that says "In $\mathbb P_2$ find the change of coordinates matrix from the basis $\mathcal B=\{1-3t^2, 2+t-5t^2,1+2t\}$ to the standard basis. Then write $t^2$ as a linear combination of the polynomials in $\mathcal B$."

I have found the change of coordinates matrix to be $$\mathcal P_{\mathcal C\leftarrow\mathcal B}=\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&1\\0&1&2\\-3&-5&0\end{matrix}\right]$$ But I'm stuck on how to write $t^2$ as a linear combination. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ -3 & -5 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

The function $t \mapsto t^2$ is represented as $(0,0,1)^T$ in the standard basis, so to find the representation in the basis $\cal B$, compute $P^{-1} (0,0,1)^T$ (note that you do **not** need to compute the matrix inverse to do this).

Here is the solution:

> $(3, -2, 1)^T$.

Here is another approach: Figure out constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $c_1(1-3t^2) + c_2 (2+t-5t^2) + c_3 (1+2t) = t^2$ for all $t$. Matching coefficients of $t^k$ gives three equations in three unknowns $c_1+ 2 c_2 + c_3 = 0$, $c_2+2 c_3 = 0$, and $-3 c_1-5 c_2 = 1$. Solving these gives the above solution.

Comment: One could pretty well answer the second question "by eye", since the constant terms in the first and second basis polynomials must cancel, so the coefficient vector has to have $(2c, -c, ?)^{T}$.  Similarly, the linear terms in the second and third basis polynomials should cancel, requiring the coefficient vector entries $(?, 2d, -d)^{T}$. Avoiding fractions in the vector leads to your result; checking the quadratic coefficients confirms this (but the more elegant matrix method may be desired on an exam).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I didn't actually intend the OP to actually compute $P^{-1}$ and then multiply. I should update my answer...

Comment: I wasn't chiding you over that.  I like having quick ways to check on answers from more sophisticated methods, when that is possible.  I could imagine, though, that an instructor might want to see students demonstrate the use of the matrix method.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I realize that. I really just included the matrix to show the error...

Comment: Actually I wrote that down wrong. I have the right matrix but wrote the basis down wrong in the problem. But I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. Is there another way you could explain perhaps? I'm just unsure of where you got the solution from.

Comment: I have corrected & added to my answer above.

Comment: How do you compute $P^{-1} (0,0,1)^T$ without computing $P^{-1}$ ??

Comment: Solve the three simultaneous equations at the bottom of my answer.